# Convert json nested dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My API generates a JSON file as output with the following structure:

```
[
{
    "Data": {
        "SensorId": "EF00BFC0",
        "SensorName": "DEVICE 05",
        "TimeStamp": 3877552823,
    },
    "ThresholdValue": {
        "SensorSubId": 1,
        "ThresholdMax": -1,
        "ThresholdMin": -1
    },
    "startUTC": 1668564000,
    "endUTC": 1668663000
},
{
    "Data": {
        "SensorId": "EF00BFC0",
        "SensorName": "DEVICE 05",
        "TimeStamp": 3877553446,
    },
    "ThresholdValue": {
        "SensorSubId": 1,
        "ThresholdMax": -1,
        "ThresholdMin": -1
    },
    "startUTC": 1668564000,
    "endUTC": 1668663000
}]
```

I want to generate a Pandas DataFrame with SensorID, SensorName, Timestamp, startUTC, and endUTC as columns.
I tried it using the below code.

```
df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(
    data, 
    record_path =['Data'], 
    meta=['startUTC', 'endUTC']
)
```

But it gives the column names as rows and generate the dataframe.
How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: `df=pd.json_normalize(data)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.json_normalize()` to get your desired output:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
{
    "Data": {
        "SensorId": "EF00BFC0",
        "SensorName": "DEVICE 05",
        "TimeStamp": 3877552823,
    },
    "ThresholdValue": {
        "SensorSubId": 1,
        "ThresholdMax": -1,
        "ThresholdMin": -1
    },
    "startUTC": 1668564000,
    "endUTC": 1668663000
},
{
    "Data": {
        "SensorId": "EF00BFC0",
        "SensorName": "DEVICE 05",
        "TimeStamp": 3877553446,
    },
    "ThresholdValue": {
        "SensorSubId": 1,
        "ThresholdMax": -1,
        "ThresholdMin": -1
    },
    "startUTC": 1668564000,
    "endUTC": 1668663000
}]
```

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df.columns = [c.replace('Data.', '') for c in df.columns]
cols_to_keep = [c for c in df.columns if 'ThresholdValue' not in c]
df = df[cols_to_keep]
df.head()
```

Output:

| startUTC | endUTC | SensorId | SensorName | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1668564000 | 1668663000 | EF00BFC0 | DEVICE 05 | 3877552823 |
| 1668564000 | 1668663000 | EF00BFC0 | DEVICE 05 | 3877553446 |